# typescript extends interface

Tags: typescript, интерфейс

Подскажите, почему в Intellisence VSCode всплывает IEntity вместо расширенного интерфейса? Обойти получается только с generic types.

Можно ли получать то же самое только без generic types?

В js скрипте Channel получает в `__proto__` методы Entity, соответственно this в них - Channel. Но базовый интерфейс не переопределяется на расширенный в методах.

```js
Channel.prototype.method = Entity.method
```

[image: скрин]

Компилируется с ошибкой, т.к. воспринимает channel as IEntity

```
file.ts:52:48 - error TS2339: Property 'hangup' does not exist on type 'IEntity'.
```

Если что, это тайпинг для node-ari-client

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Ts поддерживает в тайпингах **this**.

```
    interface IEntity {
        on(eventName: TeventType, cb: TEventCb<this>): void
    }
```

Может это кому-нибудь поможет.